# Java error how (Cannot convert double to bolean)

Tags: java, if-statement

I have been getting back in to Java after not using it for a while and tried to make a calculator one that has more then just +. However, I don't have a lot of experience coding, so I don't understand what I did wrong. It says I cant turn a double into a boolean, but that's not what I'm doing. Here is the code I get an error on.

```
if (One = UserInput.nextDouble()) {
    System.out.println("Your answer is "+ Plus +"!");
    
}else if (Two = UserInput.nextDouble()) {
    System.out.println("Your answer is "+ Sub +"!");
    
}else (Three = UserInput.nextDouble()) {
    System.out.println("Your answer is "+ Multi +"!");
```

Comment: Hint: `=` is an assignment operator. Is that what you meant to use? (I strongly suspect you only actually want to call `nextDouble` once, mind you.)

Comment: if you want to compare two values you need to use `==`, ex:
 `}else if (Two == UserInput.nextDouble()) {`

Comment: Even if you'd fix this then `nextDouble()` is called once for `One`, a second time for `Two` etc. If you are repeating yourself when programming you are probably doing it wrong: it's the computer that should perform the repetitive tasks. Try and use a local variable and / or a `switch` statement.

Comment: Thank you for you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: Once you've got something working you should probably try and post on [codereview.se] because there is a lot that goes wrong in above code, including the design, comparison with double, variable naming, print statements, spacing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single `=` sign is an assignment operator and does not return the boolean (logic) value that is necesery to check condition in the if ... else statement. Insteed `=` you should use `==` operator to compare values or Objects.equals method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "==" for comparison in if blocks.